# How to search an element in a Linked List? (c#)

Tags: c#, list, generics, search

I am given this set of code and I need to fill it up with some code above the while loop and in the While loop. I have seen some documentation but all i have seen is search methods with two arguments and this one only has one. I already wrote the part inside the while loop but im note sure if that is correct. How can I finish this code so that it searches for the value given as the parameter?

note: this is not a homework assignment where I ask you to do it for me, rather this is one of the few resources we have for studying and if you could complete this it would give me a better grasp.

When I run this code now I get this error message:
 Type "Tests.Node" does not contain a definition for "value" and no extension method "value" of type "Tests.Node" could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

```
{
  public class Node<T> where T : IComparable
{
public T Value { get; }
public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

public Node(T value, Node<T> next)
{
  this.Value = value;
  this.Next = next;
}
}

 public class LinkedList<T> where T : IComparable
  {
public Node<T> start;

public LinkedList()
{
  start = null;
}

public LinkedList(Node<T> node)
{
  start = node;
}

public Node<T> Search(T value)
{
  [here is code needed]
  while (start != null)
    if(start.value.CompareTo(value) == 0){
      return start;
    }
    start = start.next;
}
 }
   public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args){
  var list =
    new LinkedList<int>(
      new Node<int>(
        5, new Node<int>(
          7, new Node<int>(
            21, new Node<int>(
              30, null)
            )
          )
        )
    );
  var a = 21;
  var fr = list.Search(a);
}
 }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to mutate your list to start where the Search finds a match you really should assign `start` to a local variable and use that instead.  Also  you need to handle the case where there is no match, maybe with `return null;` at the end?

Comment: what do you mean to assign start to a local var?

Comment: I mean do `var curr = start;` then `while(curr != null)` and `curr = curr.Next;` and so on.  Otherwise the next time you search `start` will have been set to the Node with the matching value and you will not search the entire list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to correct solution. First of all you need to fix compiler errors -  change `value` and `next` to `Value` and `Next`, cause that how [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) on your `Node` class are called.

Next you need to add curly brackets so the `while` block will execute assignment `start = start.Next;` (currently only `if` [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements#embedded-statements) is inside while, so you will end with infinite loop)

Next you need to fix return - add `return null;` after `while` block - value you will return if nothing is found (also without it code will not compile).

Lastly you will need to fix the issue with changing the list during search (you are modifying `start` field of your `LinkedList` class with `start = start.Next`, you should not do that), introduce a temporary variable (i've name it `curr`), assign it value of `start` and use it in your while loop:

```
public Node<T> Search(T value)
{
    var curr = start;
    while (curr != null)
    {
        if (curr.Value.CompareTo(value) == 0)
        {
            return curr;
        }
        curr = curr.Next;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you, your code was almost correct, i only adjusted `var` to `Node<T>` for it to work

Comment: @user3660293 was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing `IEnumerable<Node<T>>` interface

```
public class Node<T> : IEnumerable<Node<T>> where T : IComparable {
  public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator() {
    for (Node<T> item = this; item != null; item = item.Next)
      yield return item;        
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

  ...
```

Then you can use *Linq* to query the collection:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    LinkedList<int> list = ... 

    int a = 21;

    var fr = list.start.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == a);
```